# What is the verb placement after a prepositional phrase at the beginning of a sentence?

Tags: verb-usage

What is the position of the conjugated verb after a prepositional phrase?
For example, is it

> In meinem Haus, muss ich...

Or

> In meinem Haus, ich muss...

Answer (score 11):

As usual, the verb is in second position. There is no comma, so it should read

> [In meinem Haus] [muss] [ich] ...

Where the brackets show the inseperable parts of the sentence.